# Invalid Arguments "out" parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, out

I have a method and I want use out parameter. But I am missing somethings I couldnt find. I have 3 parameters firstly long id, I am sending that ID and I am processing it and I am creating my workerName (second parameter) and workerTitle (third parameter).
My method is;

```
public static void GetWorkerInfo( long workerID, out string workerName, out string workerTitle)
{
   // Some code here
}
```

Where I am calling my method;

```
GetWorkerInfo(workerID, out workerName, out workerTitle)
```

Comment: How are your "workerName" and "workerTitle" defined before calling the method?

Comment: Are you getting this error **The out parameter 'workerTitle' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method**

Comment: @Jure thank you thats why i was getting exception

Comment: yes 
@J.SMTBCJ15 thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With C# 7 you will be able to declare your output parameters as part of method call, like this:

```
GetWorkerInfo(workerID, out var workerName, out var workerTitle);
```

Prior to switching to C# 7, however, you must declare variables that you pass as `out` parameters outside of the call:

```
string workerName;
string workerTitle;
GetWorkerInfo(workerID, out workerName, out workerTitle);
```

Comment: thank u so much actually it is my first time i am using out thats why i missed it. Thank u again

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void GetWorkerInfo(long workerID, out string workerName, out string workerTitle)
{
   workerName = "";
   workerTitle = "";
}
```

then call it like this

```
long workerID = 0;
string workerTitle;
string workerName;
GetWorkerInfo(workerID, out workerName, out workerTitle);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you were no assigning any value to those parameters specified as out parameters. Keep in mind, You should assign some values for those parameters inside the body of the method.

```
public static void GetWorkerInfo(long workerID, out string workerName, out string workerTitle)
{
   workerName = "Some value here";
   workerTitle = "Some value here also";
   // rest of code here
}
```

Now you can see the code compiles without any issues.